# How to debug error message: Cannot modify header information

Tags: plugins, functions, headers

I'm experiencing some wierdness with a custom theme in WooCommerce.
I know that WooCommerce is off-topic, but while debugging it, I've figured out that it most likely is another plugin, that is the cause of this.

There is an integration installed, that uses webhooks to integrates sales to an invoicing software. In WooCommerce >> Status >> Scheduled Actions, I can see that some of the actions fails.

[image: failed scheduled actions]

If I look in the error-log for 15:19 (when the action failed), then I see these lines:

```
[15-Jun-2021 15:19:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1329
[15-Jun-2021 15:19:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1332
[15-Jun-2021 15:21:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1329
[15-Jun-2021 15:21:04 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1332
```

But what baffles me is that some of these scheduled actions goes through as they should.
So something must sometimes add some headers too early.

So I added these lines of code in the top of the functions.php-file (as the very first thing).

```
if( headers_sent() ) {
    error_log( 'It was sent!' );
} else {
    error_log( 'Not sent.' );
}
```

... and that outputs this:

```
...
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:39 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:49 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:49 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:50 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:56 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:57 UTC] It was sent!
[22-Jun-2021 15:17:58 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:01 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:02 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:02 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:02 UTC] It was sent!
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:05 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:08 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:20 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:23 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:30 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:34 UTC] It was sent!
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:34 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:34 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:35 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:36 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:36 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:18:37 UTC] Not sent.
...
```

So now I have to find the culprit, that sends the headers at random times.

So I expanded the debugging-error-log to this:

```
if( headers_sent() ) {
    error_log( 'It was sent!' );
    $headers_list = headers_list();
    if( !empty( $headers_list ) ){
        foreach( $headers_list as $entry ){
            $str = (string) $entry;
            if( is_string( $str ) ){
                error_log( $str );
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    error_log( 'Not sent.' );
}
```

Which then gives me this:

```
...
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:01 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:02 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] It was sent!
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] It was sent!
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:03 UTC] Not sent.
[22-Jun-2021 15:46:04 UTC] Not sent.
...
```

My plan is then to download all plugins and start searching for which of them adds this code. But this seems like a tedious and manual way of doing this.

Am I missing a better way?
And could it be possible, that some plugin does it on purpose (send headers, before the functions.php-file is loaded/interpreted)?

And thinking about it a bit, then it's actually not the early headers that are the problem. It's the fact that the DOM (or body) are started too early, so further headers cannot be sent. Or what?

Comment: I thought the PHP warning told you which line had started the output? There might be a flag you can set to turn that on, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Those are the [wp_get_nocache_headers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nocache_headers/) headers. It looks like they're sent by core code for logged in users, errors and REST requests. You can probably get a call stack from wp_get_nocache_headers e.g. `error_log( print_r( debug_backtrace(), true ) );`. (Or store that in a global you can dump if headers_sent() later.)

Comment: I'd also guess those warnings aren't the cause of the scheduled job failing, but there's no harm in investigating them either.

Comment: headers_sent() can return the filename and line. Try `if( headers_sent($headers_filename, $headers_line) ) {` `error_log( 'It was sent by ' . $headers_filename . ' line ' . $headers_line );`

Comment: The failed job details the specific cause of failure - the webhook request timed out. But yeah - it's unclear how that relates to the headers error. Error logging a trace is definitely worth a shot, but it would be better to log in a try/catch around the problem path, if possible. I would start by investigating `woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async` for a reasonable location. WooCommerce also provides a separate logging facility in WooCommerce > Status > Logs - these should be reviewed.

Comment: RE: the last sentence of the question, it can be either case - something flushed output before the normal header composition routine was complete (usually the result of code producing an uncaught error which gets printed), or some code is erroneously attempting to modify response headers after the normal body output had already begun.

Comment: @bosco - Re: your last comment. Are there a way, where I can output what was sent, when the headers was attempted to be changed? To make it easier to see what I'm looking for?

Comment: Honestly I don't have much in the way of a well thought out approach here. `WP_DEBUG_LOG` w/o `_DISPLAY` might provide more information, if there's an uncaught error involved. You might also try opening an output buffer in `wp-config.php`, then use @Rup's `headers_sent()` check in an action just prior to when they should normally be sent - maybe the `send_headers` or `wp` actions - to determine whether to flush/clear the buffer or to dump it's contents to a file... that should catch the case of premature output, anyway. Did you see anything in the WooCommerce > Status > Logs?